# sklearn python error. invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, tree, python-3.6, sklearn-pandas

```
from sklearn import tree
features = [[140, 1], [130, 1], [150, 0], [170, 0]] # 1- smooth 0 - bumpy
labels = [0, 0, 1, 1] # 0 - apple 1 - orange 
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
print (clf.predict([[150, 0]]))
```

What I wanted is to make a simple first machine learning application which tells me if the fruit is an orange or an apple. After run it shows me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ursac/Desktop/hello world.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sklearn import tree
  File "C:\Users\ursac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\ursac\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

but i have already install sklearn with `pip install sklearn` in the cmd

Please help me. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install `scipy`, since it complains about that module missing.

```
pip install scipy
```

It installs `scipy`/`numpy`. As a side note - if someone has old, and new python - then `pip3` should be used, since `pip` installs modules for python 2 in this case.